# Getting a Url from inside a MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC 5 Controller I generate an email and inside is a link. I need to get the full url to an specific action.

Is there a way to generate the full URL in the controller for a given action+route ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the UrlHelper class: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

You can simply do:

`var url = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName");`

You can also pass along route parameters in an object in the third parameter:

`var url = Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { id = 123 });`

Answer (score 0):

For Full URL:

var pageUri = new Uri(HttpContext.Request.Url, Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName"));